# How to perform a has-many-through-many-to-many eloquent relation in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, has-many-through, relationships

Given the table structures below:

```
table users
  - id
  - name

table group_user
  - id
  - group_id
  - user_id

table groups
  - id
  - name

table events
  - id
  - name
  - group_id
```

We can see that a `User` has relations to `Event` objects, however it has to pass through the many-to-many relationship of a `User` to a `Group`.

I'm not sure what kind of relationship this is called... Is it a *has-many-through-many-to-many* since it has many `Event` objects through a many-to-many relationship of `users-group_user-groups`?

In any case, how do I compose a Laravel query for this?

Answer (score 0):

Given `$id` is the ID of the user performing the call, the SQL query that we are looking for looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE group_id IN (
    SELECT group_id FROM group_user WHERE user_id = $id
);
```

So if in your `group_user` table, we find that the user with `user_id = 1`  has the following group relations `group_id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, the resulting query looks like this: `SELECT * FROM events WHERE group_id IN [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];` which are what we are looking for (the events related to those groups).

1. Open up `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php`
2. Insert the following code after the `hasMany` method.

   ```
       /**
        * Define a many-through-many relationship.
        *
        * @param  string  $related
        * @param  string  $through
        * @param  string  $pivotTable
        * @param  string  $pivotKey
        * @param  string  $pivotThroughKey
        * @param  string|null  $firstKey
        * @param  string|null  $secondKey
        * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough
        */
        public function manyThroughMany($related, $through, $pivotTable, $pivotKey, $pivotThroughKey, $firstKey = null, $secondKey = null)
        {
            $relatedModel = new $related; // App\Event
            $relatedTable = $relatedModel->getTable(); // events

            $firstKey = $firstKey ?: $this->getForeignKey(); // event_id

            $throughModel = new $through; // App\Group
            $throughTable = $throughModel->getTable(); // groups

            $secondKey = $secondKey ?: $throughModel->getForeignKey(); // group_id

            return $relatedModel
                ->whereIn($secondKey, function ($query) use ($pivotTable, $pivotKey, $pivotThroughKey)
                {
                    return $query
                            ->from($pivotTable)
                            ->where($pivotKey, '=', $this->id)
                            ->select($pivotThroughKey);
                })
                ->select($relatedTable . '.*');
         }
   ```
3. Now for your model. To use the `many-through-many` relation, go to your `User` model and add the following.

   ```
       public function events()
       {
           return $this->manyThroughMany('App\Event', 'App\Group', 'group_user', 'user_id', 'group_id');
       }
   ```

The parameters are as follows:

1. The name of the target model you are interested in (i.e. `App\Event`).
2. The name of the secondary model you need to pass through (i.e. `App\Group`).
3. The name of the pivot table (i.e. `group_user`).
4. The pivot table key referencing the current model (i.e. `user_id`).
5. The pivot table key referencing the secondary model (i.e. `group_id`).

### Disclaimers

I don't really know if there's such a thing as a many-through-many relationship, or what the name for it is. This is just the code that worked for me, so I wanted to share it with people who might have the same dilemma as I did.

If there is a simpler way of doing it, please answer! If there are things I can improve, please comment. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a more supported way of doing this?  I am in a similar situation where I have Cars that have Features but those Features are grouped by Feature Types (i.e. Interior, Exterior, Safety, etc...)

Comment: No I haven't been doing much PHP or involvement with Laravel lately. I hope my explanation was clear enough for your use though!

Comment: Unfortunately not, when I load it up, there are unused variables.

Comment: You can put up a question so that others can understand your case.

Comment: I have, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133533/laravel-hasmany-many-to-many-to-one-eloquent?noredirect=1#comment69475100_41133533

Comment: Don't do this! Never edit files inside of the vendor/ folder as they will be overriden by performing `composer update`.. also the vendor folder is in Laravel's default .gitignore file so your changes won't be commited to git..

Comment: Hello- 6 years after reading the code that I recommended, I second @RicoOcepek message not to edit things on the vendor folder, as he has explained above.