# Laravel hasMany Many to Many To One Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I haven't had much luck sorting this out the Laravel way. So I pose two questions.

Given that I have a Car and that Car can have many Features, but that Features are also separated by Feature Type, how can I return all Features, separated the Feature Type, for said Car?

I have four tables, with listings_features being the pivot table:

- listings (id)
- listings_features (listing_id, feature_id)
- listings_features_types (id, type)
- listings_features_values (id, listing_feature_type_id, value)

I have the following code, which produces what I need, but when I use it, I get a Laravel error ... "Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on string" ... because I invoke it as such:

```
Listing::with(
        'features',
    )->get();
```

The code I am using to produce the data in the format I desire (not steadfast on) is

```php
public function features()
{
    $out = array();
    $features = $this->hasMany('App\Models\ListingFeature', 'listing_id', 'id')->select('feature_id')->get();
    $types = ListingFeatureType::all();
    foreach($types as $key => $obj){
        $out[$key]['listing_feature_type_id'] = $obj->id;
        $out[$key]['name'] = $obj->listing_feature_type;
        $out[$key]['features'] = ListingFeatureValue::whereIn('id', $features->toArray())->where('listing_feature_type_id', '=', $obj->id)->get()->toArray();
    }
    return json_encode($out);
}
```

Which returns:

```
[
  {
    "listing_feature_type_id": "0f40888c-3b09-40ed-aef6-0fddc1a155b6",
    "name": "Safety",
    "features": [
      {
        "id": "0ed0ad63-a6ed-4818-8c6f-ee048694dcd9",
        "listing_feature_type_id": "0f40888c-3b09-40ed-aef6-0fddc1a155b6",
        "listing_feature_text": "Anti-Lock Brakes"
      },
      {
        "id": "37abeef2-dc22-4995-8503-f89962242ea6",
        "listing_feature_type_id": "0f40888c-3b09-40ed-aef6-0fddc1a155b6",
        "listing_feature_text": "Collision Detection"
      },
      {
        "id": "3c0728e1-91f7-4f44-ac0b-429eda816692",
        "listing_feature_type_id": "0f40888c-3b09-40ed-aef6-0fddc1a155b6",
        "listing_feature_text": "Dual Airbags"
      },
      {
        "id": "4255b8b4-e71c-4059-8a22-1b9894512564",
        "listing_feature_type_id": "0f40888c-3b09-40ed-aef6-0fddc1a155b6",
        "listing_feature_text": "Side Airbags"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "listing_feature_type_id": "84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
    "name": "Interior",
    "features": [
      {
        "id": "1b89581e-1a30-4dce-9455-ab0ad4c49bcf",
        "listing_feature_type_id": "84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
        "listing_feature_text": "Privacy Glass"
      },
      {
        "id": "59e3628f-3cef-4447-9cb2-71be4a3046a4",
        "listing_feature_type_id": "84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
        "listing_feature_text": "Onboard GPS"
      },
      {
        "id": "66fe416b-98dc-45c8-979d-78f2ea7fe876",
        "listing_feature_type_id": "84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
        "listing_feature_text": "In-dash Navigation"
      },
      {
        "id": "8fe836a3-5596-4306-aac1-bae4cb596e20",
        "listing_feature_type_id": "84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
        "listing_feature_text": "Power Windows"
      },
      {
        "id": "e4addb5a-1b26-4ae3-b0ee-3b8bce892fb9",
        "listing_feature_type_id": "84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
        "listing_feature_text": "Tinted Windows"
      },
      {
        "id": "f95b8253-a2b8-4bfc-90c0-0fc656c3f200",
        "listing_feature_type_id": "84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
        "listing_feature_text": "CD Player"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "listing_feature_type_id": "8d16e8ea-3d38-48dc-8e56-00d1cc736f0d",
    "name": "Exterior",
    "features": [
      {
        "id": "3aa6dd05-dd3a-4e93-ad06-295687a8dda1",
        "listing_feature_type_id": "8d16e8ea-3d38-48dc-8e56-00d1cc736f0d",
        "listing_feature_text": "Spoiler"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here are the models (very basic, just starting out):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ListingFeatureValue extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'listings_features_values';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function type() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\ListingFeatureType', 'listing_feature_type_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ListingFeatureType extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'listings_features_types';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function values() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ListingFeatureValue', 'listing_feature_type_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ListingFeature extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'listings_features';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing = false;

}
```

How can I create the Laravel model relationships to achieve the same result set but calling it as mentioned above?  Alternatively, how can I call it as above but stop the error from occurring?

If you made it this far, thanks!

**Update:**

I wasn't able to get it working as is, I got a SQL error which makes me feel like I need a belongsToManyThrough so I can specify the table names:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ad_l5.listing_listing_feature' doesn't exist (SQL: select `listings_features`.*, `listing_listing_feature`.`listing_id` as `pivot_listing_id`, `listing_listing_feature`.`listing_feature_id` as `pivot_listing_feature_id` from `listings_features` inner join `listing_listing_feature` on `listings_features`.`id` = `listing_listing_feature`.`listing_feature_id` where `listing_listing_feature`.`listing_id` in (b266c874-1cef-4f49-b65f-f91ddaaf6aee, e93674ca-3f82-45d8-9961-e8569cac164b))
```

But using the exact code posted as the answer below from @Carter Fort and changing the features() method to

```php
return $this->belongsToMany(ListingFeatureValue::class, 'listings_features', 'listing_id', 'feature_id');
```

Also adding to the model ListingFeatureValue

```php
public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ListingFeatureType::class, 'listing_feature_type_id', 'id');
    }
```

I get the output of:

```js
"featuresByType": {
"": [
{
"id": "3aa6dd05-dd3a-4e93-ad06-295687a8dda1",
"listing_feature_type_id": "8d16e8ea-3d38-48dc-8e56-00d1cc736f0d",
"listing_feature_text": "Spoiler",
"pivot": {
"listing_id": "e93674ca-3f82-45d8-9961-e8569cac164b",
"feature_id": "3aa6dd05-dd3a-4e93-ad06-295687a8dda1"
},
"type": {
"id": "8d16e8ea-3d38-48dc-8e56-00d1cc736f0d",
"listing_feature_type": "Exterior"
}
},
{
"id": "f95b8253-a2b8-4bfc-90c0-0fc656c3f200",
"listing_feature_type_id": "84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
"listing_feature_text": "CD Player",
"pivot": {
"listing_id": "e93674ca-3f82-45d8-9961-e8569cac164b",
"feature_id": "f95b8253-a2b8-4bfc-90c0-0fc656c3f200"
},
"type": {
"id": "84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
"listing_feature_type": "Interior"
}
},
{
"id": "66fe416b-98dc-45c8-979d-78f2ea7fe876",
"listing_feature_type_id": "84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
"listing_feature_text": "In-dash Navigation",
"pivot": {
"listing_id": "e93674ca-3f82-45d8-9961-e8569cac164b",
"feature_id": "66fe416b-98dc-45c8-979d-78f2ea7fe876"
},
"type": {
"id": "84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
"listing_feature_type": "Interior"
}
},
{
"id": "0ed0ad63-a6ed-4818-8c6f-ee048694dcd9",
"listing_feature_type_id": "0f40888c-3b09-40ed-aef6-0fddc1a155b6",
"listing_feature_text": "Anti-Lock Brakes",
"pivot": {
"listing_id": "e93674ca-3f82-45d8-9961-e8569cac164b",
"feature_id": "0ed0ad63-a6ed-4818-8c6f-ee048694dcd9"
},
"type": {
"id": "0f40888c-3b09-40ed-aef6-0fddc1a155b6",
"listing_feature_type": "Safety"
}
},
  ...
```

That is better than I was at, but it would be nice if the results were grouped by type then features within then instead of it being each feature with a type attached.  Makes it harder to parse for display.  Thanks for the help thus far!

**Update 2**

These would be my schema files:

```php
// listings
Schema::create('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('id');
    $table->string('title');
});

// listings to features pivot
Schema::create('listings_features', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('listing_id');
    $table->string('feature_id');
});

// feature types (i.e. Safety)
Schema::create('listings_features_types', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->string('id');
    $table->string('listing_feature_type');
});

// feature values (i.e. Anti-Lock Brakes)
Schema::create('listings_features_values', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->string('id');
    $table->string('listing_feature_type_id'); // links to listings_features_types
    $table->string('listing_feature_text');
});
```

**Update 3**
Making the changes from the answer below (I will post all code once working) I get close to what I would like.

```json
"features": [
{
"id": "3aa6dd05-dd3a-4e93-ad06-295687a8dda1",
"listing_feature_type_id": "8d16e8ea-3d38-48dc-8e56-00d1cc736f0d",
"listing_feature_text": "Spoiler",
"pivot": {
"listing_id": "e93674ca-3f82-45d8-9961-e8569cac164b",
"feature_id": "3aa6dd05-dd3a-4e93-ad06-295687a8dda1"
},
"type": {
"id": "8d16e8ea-3d38-48dc-8e56-00d1cc736f0d",
"listing_feature_type": "Exterior"
}
},
{
"id": "f95b8253-a2b8-4bfc-90c0-0fc656c3f200",
"listing_feature_type_id": "84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
"listing_feature_text": "CD Player",
"pivot": {
"listing_id": "e93674ca-3f82-45d8-9961-e8569cac164b",
"feature_id": "f95b8253-a2b8-4bfc-90c0-0fc656c3f200"
},
"type": {
"id": "84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
"listing_feature_type": "Interior"
}
},
{
"id": "66fe416b-98dc-45c8-979d-78f2ea7fe876",
"listing_feature_type_id": "84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
"listing_feature_text": "In-dash Navigation",
"pivot": {
"listing_id": "e93674ca-3f82-45d8-9961-e8569cac164b",
"feature_id": "66fe416b-98dc-45c8-979d-78f2ea7fe876"
},
"type": {
"id": "84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
"listing_feature_type": "Interior"
}
```

// ....
    ]

What I would like is:

```json
{
   "feature_types":[
      {
         "type":{
            "id":"8d16e8ea-3d38-48dc-8e56-00d1cc736f0d",
            "listing_feature_type":"Interior",
            "features":[
               {
                  "id":"3aa6dd05-dd3a-4e93-ad06-295687a8dda1",
                  "listing_feature_type_id":"8d16e8ea-3d38-48dc-8e56-00d1cc736f0d",
                  "listing_feature_text":"GPS"
               },
               {
                  "id":"66fe416b-98dc-45c8-979d-78f2ea7fe876",
                  "listing_feature_type_id":"84dcce5c-34b9-4c8b-9066-5b20a42cf4cd",
                  "listing_feature_text":"In-dash Navigation"
               },

            ]            "pivot":{
               "listing_id":"e93674ca-3f82-45d8-9961-e8569cac164b",
               "feature_id":"f95b8253-a2b8-4bfc-90c0-0fc656c3f200"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: care to post your model (*listing_features* tables) your `public function features()` doesn't feel right..

Comment: Also, before you ask, I am making an API to an existing app which is why the table names and other stuff are defined. :)

Comment: so basically you want to be able retrieve all `listings` and each `listings` have `listings_feature_types` that contains `listings_feature_values`, am i right?

Comment: Exactly. <text for length limit>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a Many-to-Many relationship between the `Listing` and the `ListingFeatureValue` models, then group the related listing features for a given listing by their type using the `groupBy` Collection method.

The **Listing** model:

```
class Listing extends Model {

    protected $hidden = [
        'features'
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'feature_types'
    ];

    public function features(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(ListingFeatureValue::class, 'listings_features', 'listing_id', 'feature_id');
    }

    public function getFeatureTypesAttribute()
    {
        return $this->features->groupBy(function ($feature, $key) {
            return $feature->type->id;
        })->map(function($features, $key){
            $type = ListingFeatureType::find($key);
            $type->features = $features;
            return $type;
        })->values();
    }

}
```

The `getFeatureTypesAttribute()` is the star of the show here, because you can combine that with the `appends` array to force the Eloquent model to append that to any `toArray()` calls to the model instance, which is what `toJson()` uses when converting your model to JSON.

It may seem a little convoluted to first fetch all the listing values then divide them using the `groupBy` and `map` collection methods, but there is no native Eloquent mechanism for using `hasManyThrough` via many-to-many relationships. There's a [different approach here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788844/hasmanythrough-with-one-to-many-relationship/23789210#23789210) if you don't like this one.

The **ListingFeatureValue** model:

```
class ListingFeatureValue extends Model
{
    public $table = 'listings_features_values';

    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ListingFeatureType::class, 'feature_type_id');
    }
}
```

I'm showing this model here because the `type()` relationship is called in the `getFeaturesByTypeAttribute()` method above and didn't want there to be any confusion.

And, just for the sake of completeness, the **ListingFeatureType** model:

```
class ListingFeatureType extends Model
{
    public $table = "listings_features_types";

    public function listings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ListingFeatureValue::class, 'listing_feature_type_id');
    }
}
```

If you wanted to eager-load the listings with their features and types for a full output of all your listings, you could do so like this:

```
App\Listing::with('features.type')->get()->toJson();
```

My migration files look like this:

```
//create_listings_table
Schema::create('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('uuid');
    $table->timestamps();
});

//create_listings_features_values_table
Schema::create('listings_features_values', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('listing_feature_text');
    $table->integer('listing_feature_type_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
});

//create_listings_features_types_table    
Schema::create('listings_features_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

//create_listings_features_table
Schema::create('listings_features', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->integer('listing_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('listing_feature_id')->unsigned();
});
```

You can learn more about the Collection methods here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#available-methods

...and eager-loading here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

...and many-to-many relationships here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: However, I was able to get a version working but the output is weird.  I will update the original post.  I also feel like I need a belongsTomanyThrough based on the SQL generated.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the migration code for the pivot table that you'll need. You'll also need to attach/sync your listings with their listing features, like so: `$listing->features()->sync($arrayOfListingFeatureIDs)`

Comment: You can read more about managing many-to-many relationships here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Based on Update 2: There is a missing table though, which is the core of my issue.  I have four tables.  listings, listings_features, listings_features_types, listings_features_values.  listings holds the listings, listings_features is the pivot table to listings_features_values which has the value of the feature.  listings_features_values also has listings_features_type_id to link to listings_features_types.  I will post up mock schemas.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to use the `listings_features` as a pivot table to connect the `Listing` and `ListingFeatureValue` models together.

Comment: We are very close.  I basically want the inverse of what I will post as Update 3.  When we get it all working, I will post up all of my models and migrations to help others as this has already been starred three times.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new `getFeatureTypesAttribute` that will return the collection you're looking for.

Comment: Perfect! I will update the OP with everything in a bit.  Bounty awarded!